# What file(s) does OS X store its version number in?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, version

I've seen it before, but after a few minutes of Googling I'm coming up empty -- does anyone know/remember what file OS X stores its version number in?

I'm trying to figure out the version of OS X on an external drive without booting into it.  Note that solutions like the one [here](https://coderwall.com/p/4yz8dq) won't work as they all require you to be booted up with the drive in question.

Comment: Just realized I can probably solve this by going to System Preferences' "Startup Disk" preference pane, but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think I figured it out: On the disk in question, view the contents of the file "/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist". Thanks to JonoC at [deploystudio.com/Forums/viewtopic.php?id=5541](http://deploystudio.com/Forums/viewtopic.php?id=5541) for the tip about SystemVersion.plist and Justin Daigle at [justindaigle.com/blog/2010/02/…](http://justindaigle.com/blog/2010/02/tutorial-change-mac-os-x-system-version/) for the absolute path to that file. (And, yes -- by the way -- System Preferences' "Startup Disk" preference pane did also show me the OS X version of my external disk.)